# How to dynamically set background color for UITableView section headers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm working on implementing UITableView section headers similar to the Photos app on iPhone. The top header view should have a grey background and the other header views should have a white background. Based on that I have a couple of questions I need help with:

1. How do I find out which section header is on top (e.g. adjacent to the nav bar)? Note, that the navigation bar is translucent (meaning it displays cells below itself), so I can't go by finding visible cells and then retrieving section based on that.
2. What should be the approach to change background color of the top section header to a different color and then back to the original color when it's no longer a top one?

Comment: Are you asking about section header?

Comment: @Morpheus - yes, sections headers.

Answer (score 0):

Make the property `NSUInteger sectionPath` and initialize it with `0` in `viewDidLoad`.

Create a headerView and for specific section change backgroundColor of that view.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 30)];

    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, headerView.frame.size.width, headerView.frame.size.height)];

    headerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    headerLabel.text = [titleArray objectAtIndex:section];

    if(section == sectionPath) {
        headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    }
    else {
        headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];    

    return headerView;
}
```

To dynamically find the top-most header in `UITableView` during scrolling

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    for (NSIndexPath* i in [yourTableViewName indexPathsForVisibleRows]) {
      sectionPath = [i indexAtPosition:0];
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't work. I need the headers change color dynamically based on which one is on top. So once the header is scrolled away, it needs to change color to white. And then the one that showed up on top needs to switch to gray.

Comment: Means, on scrolling you want that the topmost header will have gray background color?

Comment: correct. On scrolling the topmost header to stay gray, and the rest be white. Exactly as it is in the Photos app on iOS7